# Why does ScalikeJdbc require an Execution Context when it has a Thread Pool?

Tags: scala, scalikejdbc

In this example an Execution Context is used to process the future.

Why is this used when Scalike has a built in connection pool?

Shouldn't the Future use one of the pool threads to execute?  It seems like a real waste to ForkJoin a thread just to wait on the Future while another thread does the IO work.

http://scalikejdbc.org/documentation/transaction.html

```
object FutureDB {
  implicit val ec = myOwnExecutorContext
  def updateFirstName(id: Int, firstName: String)(implicit session: DBSession): Future[Int] = {
    Future { 
      blocking {
        session.update("update users set first_name = ? where id = ?", firstName, id)
      } 
    }
  }
  def updateLastName(id: Int, lastName: String)(implicit session: DBSession): Future[Int] = {
    Future { 
      blocking {
        session.update("update users set last_name = ? where id = ?", lastName, id)
      } 
    }
  }
}

object Example {
  import FutureDB._
  val fResult = DB futureLocalTx { implicit s =>  
    updateFirstName(3, "John").map(_ => updateLastName(3, "Smith"))
  }
}

Example.fResult.foreach(println(_))
```

Answer (score 4):

> Why is this used when Scalike has a built in connection pool?

A connection pool is not a thread pool. A connection pool is simply a collection of open database connections kept by some object that handles opening, closing, and provisioning them to other APIs. Connection pools generally know nothing of threads. You can have a connection pool with 50 open connections in it, but if your application only has one thread, you will only be able to use one at a time (with a blocking API like this), as executing a query through a connection will block whatever thread called it.

An `ExecutionContext` is required so that you can provide your own thread pool, in any way you want. That could mean the default context `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicit.global`, a fixed thread pool, or fork join pool of your own creation, etc. This allows you to tune your application based on your performance needs, without being tied down to a single `ExecutionContext`.